# CSV Export of visible rows

Tags: jquery, csv, export, visible

I have a table in which a user filters the rows by a dropdown which simply hides the rows they do not want to see.

What I would like to do is export to CSV only the currently visible rows.

Anyone ever done something like this before? I'm using `hide()` and `show()` to hide/show the table rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else that is looking for a similar solution, I did find something finally. Here it is.

```
jQuery.fn.toCSV = function() {
      var data = $(this).first(); //Only one table
      var csvData = [];
      var tmpArr = [];
      var tmpStr = '';
      data.find("tr:visible").each(function() {
          if($(this).find("th").length) {
              $(this).find("th").each(function() {
                tmpStr = $(this).text().replace(/"/g, '""');
                tmpArr.push('"' + tmpStr + '"');
              });
              csvData.push(tmpArr);
          } else {
              tmpArr = [];
                 $(this).find("td").each(function() {
                    if($(this).text().match(/^-{0,1}\d*\.{0,1}\d+$/)) {
                        tmpArr.push(parseFloat($(this).text()));
                    } else {
                        tmpStr = $(this).text().replace(/"/g, '""');
                        tmpArr.push('"' + tmpStr + '"');
                    }
                });
              csvData.push(tmpArr.join(','));
          }
      });
      var output = csvData.join('\n');
      var uri = 'data:application/csv;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(output);
      window.open(uri);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a quick one-shot way of doing this unfortunately.
What you can however do:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> to select only visible rows.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> copy.

Open a new sheet.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> paste.

Then save the new sheet to CSV.